# Zend_Soap_Server parameters must be ordered?

Tags: php, zend-framework, soap, zend-soap

I have a strange issue using my Zend_soap_server.

if i have a method that looks like

```
/**
     * This method will say hello
     * 
     * @param string $param1
     * @param integer $param2
     * @param integer $param3
     * @throws Zend_Exception
     */
public method($param1, $param2, $param3)
```

and my xml request looks like

```
<param2 xsi:type="xsd:int">0</param2>
<param1 xsi:type="xsd:string">hello</param1>
<param3 xsi:type="xsd:int">2</param3>
```

it happens that param1 is 0 (should be hello)
param2 is hello (should be 0)
param3 is 2.

All works if my request was ordered

```
<param1 xsi:type="xsd:string">hello</param1>
<param2 xsi:type="xsd:int">0</param2>
<param3 xsi:type="xsd:int">2</param3>
```

Any idea about why do i have that situation? And how do i fix it?

Thank you for your support, and sorry for my english.

Comment: That seems like a pretty big limitation.  I would think the order in the XML should not matter.  Double check your C style comment blocks and make sure you have `@var string public $param1` on the class declarations.  AutoDiscovery is very dependent on the use of reflection and those comments have to be just right.  Not sure how this would really tie in to what you are describing though.  Otherwise maybe try passing a WSDL to the Zend_Soap_Server constructor.

Comment: i try that, nothing has changed. about reflections for autodiscover i see that my wsdl is just fine. So my comments are good i think.